# What does pausing the AI do in Hearts of Iron 4?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

There is a console command known as 'ai'. When I enter it, a message is displayed 'AI has been paused'. Does this mean that all the AI nations stop doing stuff (stops production, construction etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the AI will prevent the AI fro giving any **new** orders (troop movements, construction etc.). However, orders already issues will still be executed, like construction in progress and troops already on the move.